# Get a bean (programmatically registered) from Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I registered a bean programmatically:

```
@Autowired
private GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

[...]

applicationContext.registerBean("a0", A.class, () -> new A(0));

// make sure to set up the bean
applicationContext.getBean("a0");
```

When I want to get this bean by name, it works and always returns the same instance:

```
applicationContext.getBean("a0");
```

But when I want to get all beans of type A.class, it returns en empty Map:

```
Map<String, A> as = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(A.class);
```

as = [] !!!

I'm working with Spring 5.0,
Why does Spring consider have no bean of type A in my context while I can retrieve them by name ?

Comment: Does `BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(applicationContext,
      A.class)`  works?

Comment: Yes sir, it works.
I consider my issue solved but if anyone knows why my context cannot find itself my beans, I'm still interested in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead [BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryUtils.html#beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors-org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory-java.lang.Class-):

```
BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(applicationContext, A.class)
```

See [Spring forum answer](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/55500-why-doesn-t-getbeansoftype-does-not-use-parent-application-context):

> Does not consider any hierarchy this factory may participate in. Use BeanFactoryUtils' beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors to include beans in ancestor factories too.